# MVC2 complex type visual studio 2010 .net framework 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a stored procedure `usp_getCashCommissionCustomer` like this:

```
Select 
    cw.Customercode, name, state as Province, City, Suburb,
    Balance As HMCommission, MBalance as  MTNCommission 
from 
    customerwallet cw
inner join
    customer cu on cw.customercode = cu.customercode
where 
    iscash = 1
    and (balance + mbalance) > 0
order by 
    customercode
```

On click on `customercode` I should open create view of follwing table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CustomerLedger]
(
    [ID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CustomerCode] [varchar](25) NULL,
    [TransactionType] [varchar](1) NULL,
    [Description] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [TransactionDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [Amount] [float] NULL,
    [IsProcessed] [bit] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Please help me.

I am new to ASP.NET MVC 2

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether you are using ORM or not. If you are not any ORM then you may see an approach to fill the view using stored procedure mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7759063/asp-net-mvc-3-models-stored-procedures). IF you are using ORM such as L@S or entity framework you may get start from [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/08/16/linq-to-sql-part-6-retrieving-data-using-stored-procedures.aspx). 
If You want popup of view you find the tutorial [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/146396/A-Comparison-of-Three-jQuery-Modal-Dialogs-for-ASP)

Comment: i am using entity framework. i am displaying out put of the storeprocedure on a grid.i have created complextype for output of grid. when i click on customercode it should open create view of customerledger model .

Comment: Then follow the tutorial of jquey popup